# Xvnc4 numlock does not work

Tags: linux, vnc, vncserver

I have a Xvnc4 session running such as

```
Xvnc4 :23012 -desktop test -auth /home/myuser/.Xauthority -geometry 1280x1024 -depth 16 -rfbwait 30000 -rfbauth /home/myuser/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 28912 -pn -fp /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Type1/,/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Speedo/,/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/misc/,/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/75dpi/,/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/100dpi/,/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc/,/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/,/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/,/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/ -co /etc/X11/rgb -rfbport 23012
```

which is created with the following command:

```
vnc4server $DISPLAY -rfbport $APP_PORT -geometry 1280x1024
```

But the "numlock" is not working. I can't type any numbers with it.

I have tried several things, I think that the most relevant test is the one related with numlockx. It's not able to put numlock on either.

```
$ DISPLAY=:23012 numlockx status
Numlock is off
$ DISPLAY=:23012 numlockx on
$ DISPLAY=:23012 numlockx status
Numlock is off
```

How can I make the numlock of the keyboard work?
Alternatively, how can I keep the numlock always on?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Linux Mint 20.1. I installed numlockx and set my login to turn on numlock. For some reason it doesn't work - it's on in BIOS, it's on until I log in, but turns off at login. I searched around & found nothing.

So, I checked numlockx man page: I put a custom command in "Startup Applications" - 'numlock on'.

Hope that helps.

I think I'll rename it 'mumlockx'.